# Propane tank usage in wintertime

Tags: equipment, boil, techniques

Today is 14°F (-10°C) here in the northern suburbs of MA.  In wintertime it can be tough to brew outside if you are a propane cooker brewer such as myself.
When the tank is going full bore it tends to frost up and get really cold as that liquid propane in the tank vaporizes.
I don't know if the propane actually freezes, but as it gets colder and colder the flow rate can trickle to a stand still and the boil becomes difficult to maintain.

Anyone else notice that?
What do you do to combat it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two tanks and two burners actually.  What I do is fire off about 2 gallons of water and get it up to about 150F.  Then I pour that one of those part tubs (for keeping a half barrel cpacked with ice).  And I put my propane tank in there.  The water only comes up to the top of the base ring on the tank.  The tank isn't submerged in the hot water.

I put the tub on top of a couple folded down cardboard boxes to insulate it a bit from the floor, and I cover the top of it with a few old beach towels to help trap the steam.  This seems to keep the tank from getting too cold and I can get through an entire session.  If I need too I can fire up the second burner with the second tank and get a little more hot water going if necessary.

Comment: That's pretty damn smart!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in PA on cold days. I also have two tanks (three if you count the one in the grill) so I usually cycle them first to my boil rig, then as they lose power there either into the mash rig where a slow flame is beneficial or directly into the grill.

On a very cold brew day it means I always start the boil with a full tank and have a second (non-frozen) one on hand to back it up.

The grill rarely suffers from this as it consumes it a comparatively slower rate so I can usually move it directly from a failing boil onto the grill and keep cooking the brew burgers...

Comment: Jeesh, cooking burgers and brewing at the same time in sub freezing temps... I just order pizza when I brew in the cold along with a strong dopplebock to keep my warm.